# Android Start Service or Bind Service

Tags: android, service

I am trying to decide whether i Should Bind or Start a service in Android.

Basically I have implemented a User Tracking service to be used by my application.

From the documentation I understood that binding a service is when you want other applications to communicate with your service. And starting a service is when you only have a service specifically for an application.

However, I want to be able to keep the service running even when the application is not on the running applications list (i.e. the list on the third button on android devices).

Would binding the service be better than just starting it?

Answer (score 2):

A bound service is destroyed once all the clients unbind. A bound service offers a client-server interface that allows components to interact with the service, send requests, get results, and even do so across processes with interprocess communication (IPC).

A start service can run indefinitely. Usually, a started service performs a single operation and does not return a result to the caller.

Since you want to keep running the service irrespective of whether application is running, then start service is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

From what i understand, what you should do is the following:

- The first time you open the application you should start your service and let it do its work on the background and return START_STICKY from the onStartCommand() so the service will run as you want even if your app is not, until you explicitly call stopService().
- Whenever you open your app while your service is running you should bind to your service if you want to display data from it or something.